# Why do we need endianness here?

Tags: python, numpy, endianness

I am reading a [source-code](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py) which downloads the zip-file and reads the data into numpy array. The code suppose to work on macos and linux and here is the snippet that I see:

```
def _read32(bytestream):
    dt = numpy.dtype(numpy.uint32).newbyteorder('>')
    return numpy.frombuffer(bytestream.read(4), dtype=dt)
```

This function is used in the following context:

```
with gzip.open(filename) as bytestream:
    magic = _read32(bytestream)
```

It is not hard to see what happens here, but I am puzzled with the purpose of `newbyteorder('>')`. I read the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.newbyteorder.html), and know what endianness mean, but can not understand why exactly developer added newbyteorder (in my opinion it is not really needed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because data downloaded is in big endian format as described in source page: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

> All the integers in the files are stored in the MSB first (high
>   endian) format used by most non-Intel processors. Users of Intel
>   processors and other low-endian machines must flip the bytes of the
>   header.

Comment: If you take a look at the code at line 45 you see `    data = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype=numpy.uint8)`. This make mess the things a little bit. Why does in this line of code the endianness  is not specified?

Comment: Because data type `uint8` is just 1 byte long. Endianness is meaningful only for multi-byte data types.

Answer (score 4):

It is just a way of ensuring that the bytes are interpreted from the resulting array in the correct order, regardless of a system's native byteorder.

By default, the built in NumPy integer dtypes will use the byteorder that is native to your system. For example, my system is little-endian, so simply using the dtype `numpy.dtype(numpy.uint32)` will mean that values read into an array from a buffer with the bytes in big-endian order will not be interpreted correctly.

If `np.frombuffer` is to meant to recieve bytes that are known to be in a particular byteorder, the best practice is to modify the dtype using `newbyteorder`. This is mentioned in the [documents for `np.frombuffer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html):

> Notes
>
> If the buffer has data that is not in machine byte-order, this should be specified as part of the data-type, e.g.:
>
> ```
> >>> dt = np.dtype(int)
> >>> dt = dt.newbyteorder('>')
> >>> np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=dt)
> ```
>
> The data of the resulting array will not be byteswapped, but will be
> interpreted correctly.